# Format a usb drive using format command

Tags: vb.net, shell, process, drive, usb-drive

Have been trying to run the format.com command through either a `Shell` or `Process.Start` methods without success and need some guidance as to where I am going wrong.

Note - I have placed a copy of format.com in my local working directory (C:\AEL)

```
Shell("C:\AEL\Format.com " & "G:" & " /q")
```

The result from this is an error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>   Additional information: File not found.

I have tried without a full path with the same result as well as a full path to the System32 directory. AEL is m,y own local working directory.

If I use the `Process.Start` method

```
Process.Start("C:\AEL\format.com " & "G:" & " /q")
```

I get the following error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Pulling hair out - there must be something simple I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further reading have used the following:

```
Dim FDrive As New ProcessStartInfo
        FDrive.FileName = "format.com"
        FDrive.Arguments = Mid(TDir, 6, 2) & ForQ & Mid(TDir, 9, 4) & "X"
        FDrive.UseShellExecute = False
        FDrive.CreateNoWindow = True
        FDrive.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        FDrive.RedirectStandardInput = True
        Process.Start(FDrive)
```

This works fine, allowing me to select for Full or Quick format through the ForQ variable.

Would still like to understand why the

```
process.start("Drivename", "Arguments")
```

method is not applicable to use. Was trying to understand the differences based on:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2

which describes the Start(String,string) usage.

However, would now like to know how to capture the endpoint of the format process I have just started.
Have had to resort to a timer to check

```
Private Sub TimerX_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerX.Tick
    FProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("format.com")
    If FProcess.Count > 0 Then : Exit Sub : End If
    TimerX.Stop() : TimerX.Enabled = False
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup(TDir & " FORMAT COMPLETED", 3, "FORMAT DRIVE REQUEST")
    Can = 0 : ButtonStatus()
End Sub
```

Is there a simpler way to monitor the end of the format process I could use?

Answer (score 0):

> there must be something simple I am missing

Yes, there is.  The documentation.  If you try to use a type or member and it doesn't work, the very first thing you should do is read the documentation for that type or member.  Microsoft didn't spend hundreds or possibly thousands of man hours to write the documentation for nothing.

If you had done that, you'd know that you need to provide the file execute and the commandline arguments for the process separately:

```
Process.Start("C:\AEL\format.com", "G: /q")
```

You'll notice that I also refrained from concatenation two literal `Strings` there two, which is silly.

Comment: That I had understood the documentation  but clearly not. Just teaching  myself so step by step. Thought I was using the Start(string,string) version of the option and had used it to try with ' Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.htm")' example so thought it would work with format.com as well. Still reading more documentation to understand the separate arguments options  but your comments appreciated.

Comment: To format code in a comment, wrap it in grave accents rather than single quotes.  The grave (French, pronounced "grarv") is often referred to as a "back tick" and is on the same key as the tilde (~) on a US layout keyboard.  You can do the same for inline code snippets in questions and answers too, but you should definitely use the 4-soace indent for code blocks, as you have done.  I've added a couple of edits with formatting to your original question, so you can open that for editing to see what it looks like if needs be.